# Perfect iphone rss project

Tags: iphone, xml, memory-leaks, rss, nsxmlparser

i have nsxmlparser project but i have leak problem. i search all over the interent for a solution but i didn't find one :(.
can someone give me code for Perfect nsxmlparser project/code without leaks?

thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

NSXMLParser is leaky on iOS. I recommend using libxml instead.

And, BTW if you're looking for a good RSS parsing library, I recommend [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser)